# VBA Not Renaming New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code below should add a new sheet and then give it the name from input box. I've went through a couple of iterations of this and cannot get it to work.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWS as Worksheet, sName as String

Again:
    sName = Inputbox ("Enter Sheet Name")
    If sName = vbNull Then Exit Sub

For Each oWs in Worksheets
    If LCase (sName) = LCase (oWS.Name) Then GoTo Again
Next oWS

Set oWS = Worksheets.Add(,ActiveSheet)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Application.InputBox` because it returns false if empty.  Having `Goto` statements in your code is kind of like inviting people over to when your house is dirty.  Finally, added some code to handle invalid sheet names.

```
Sub AddWorksheet()
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Do
        result = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Sheet Name", Title:=IIf(Len(result) = 0, "Create Worksheet", result & " - Exists"), Type:=2)
        If result = False Then Exit Sub
    Loop Until Not WorksheetExists(result)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Name = result
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If MsgBox("Try Again?", vbYesNo, "Invalid Name") = vbYes Then AddWorksheet
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(result As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If LCase(result) = LCase(ws.Name) Then
            WorksheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: In `WorksheetExists` I would use `Set ws = Worksheets(result)` preceeded by `On Error Resume Next` and then `If Not ws Is Nothing Then WorksheetExists = True` for best performance, although it will have impact only when there are many worksheets or function is called multiple times in a loop which is not the case for OP.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk thanks.  I was 50 50 with that idea but decided to go with the OPs code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Realized answer right as I posted it. Will prob delete. Adding answer below for now. Im strictly doing this for practice, so if anyone knows of other ways to accomplish this (and feels like sharing) I will gladly review your method!

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWS as Worksheet, sName as String

Again:
    sName = Inputbox ("Enter Sheet Name")
    If sName = vbNull Then Exit Sub

For Each oWs in Worksheets
    If LCase (sName) = LCase (oWS.Name) Then GoTo Again
Next oWS

Set oWS = Worksheets.Add(,ActiveSheet)
ActiveSheet.Name = sName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewSheet()
    Dim sName As String

    sName = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
    If sName = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsThereSheet(sName) Then Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = sName
End Sub

Function IsThereSheet(sName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsThereSheet = Not Worksheets(sName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

as you can see, no need for looping through sheets: just try and get the worksheet object with given name to see if it's already there

also notice that there's no need to LCase sheet names before checking since Excel won't let you have both a "Sheet1" and "sheet1" sheet